Is It Allowed To Post Ideas About Solution To Collutz Conjecture Here
I am new new here. Am I allowed to discuss my ideas about proof of the Collutz Conjecture?

Each SE site has a help page listing the topics which can be asked on it. You‘ll find the one relevant for Ask Different here.

While not in scope for this site, it may very well be for the Mathematics Stack Exchange site. I'd recommend checking out their Help Centre.
